# How to build ArcGIS line buffer based on raster depth value

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap, buffer, polygon-creation

I want to create a script in Python for ArcGIS that generates a buffer around a line feature, but I want the width to vary depending on the underlying raster layer. Specifically I want to create a buffer along a line that’s width is depth dependent by using a GEBCO elevation GeoTIFF. The buffer would be a percentage of water depth. My issue is that I cannot think of a way to do this. How can I sample each overlapping cell value along the line and build a polygon buffer based on those values? I feel like this has to have been done before but I can’t find any examples.

I have not written any code for this yet as I have not come up with a good solution for how to do it yet. I think I’d want to follow along the line by some step interval and add polygon vertices on each side buffered out by some water depth percentage. I’m not sure if there is a better approach through.

Comment: Since you have a raster cost surface, this is really a Spatial Analyst problem, not a vector one. Convert the vector to raster, and model it in SA.

Comment: You could maybe look at something using extract values to points or something, having created points along your line feature at an appropriate interval, probably related to your pixel value. Can you maybe elaborate on what resolution you would be looking for the buffer to change width, every pixel, or a smoother result along a longer line segment, made from say the average of several pixels that intersect the line segment?

Comment: I think your question would be much improved if you included a sketch of your inputs and desired outputs? For example what if this line is at the coast, there is no water depth?